# Comparing means of three groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, statistical-significance

When I want to compare the means between two groups I use a t-test.
But how do I check whether the means of three groups are equal or statistically different?

E.g. compare the average labour productivity of small, medium and large firms.

Comment: user 21342 - you have been given a reasonable answer to your question. If that answer is acceptable, you should really do the right thing and accept it - I doubt anyone is going to offer a more substantive one. If it is not acceptable, you should indicate why.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [One-way analysis of variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_ANOVA)

> In statistics, one-way analysis of variance (abbreviated one-way ANOVA) is a technique used to compare means of two or more samples (using the F distribution).